# Change method in a statement conditionally

Tags: javascript

Is possible to change a method according to the input without the need to duplicate a function? For example, if the variable `intent` assumes the value `payment`, the method applied to the object `stripe` is `paymentIntents`. If `intent` is `setup`, then the method applied to the object `stripe` is `setupIntent`

```
let intent = req.userIntent

stripe.paymentIntents.update("teste")
```

What I wouldn't like to do is:

```
let intent = req.userIntent

if (intent = "payment") {
     stripe.paymentIntents.update("teste")      
   } else if (intent = "setup") {  
     stripe.setupIntents.update("teste")
 }
```

Clarifying, the code is way bigger, but the same for both situations, except by the method (`paymentIntents` or `setupIntent`), and I don't want to repeat the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator in combination with bracket notation:

```
const prop = intent === 'payment'
  ? 'paymentIntents'
  : intent === 'setup'
    ? 'setupIntents'
    : null;
stripe[prop]?.update("teste");
```

or, you may be able to do

```
stripe[intent + 'intents']?.update("teste");
```

Note that `=` is assignment, not comparison. You want `===` to compare, not `=`.

If the `intent` can be *only* `'payment'` or `'setup'`, it's easier:

```
stripe[intent === 'payment' ? 'paymentIntents' : 'setupIntents'].update("teste");
```

or

```
stripe[intent + 'intents'].update("teste");
```

Comment: Amazing! When complex things are solved with elegance!  I didn't know about this prop resource. Worked perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper object that will hold proper key related to user input.

```
const o = {
   payment: 'paymentIntents',
   setup: 'setupIntents',
};
```

```js
let intent = req.userIntent;

const o = {
   payment: 'paymentIntents',
   setup: 'setupIntents',
};

stripe[o[intent]].update("teste");
```

**Note**: You can extend the helper object with new fields to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Is the idea to economize on repeated code? You can build the stripe-calling the function from the string...

```
function makeAStripeFN(intent) {
  return new Function(`return stripe.${intent}Intents`);
}
```

Use it like this...

```
makeAStripeFN(req.userIntent)().update("teste")
```

Proving it with a mock stripe object...

```js
class MockStripe {
  get paymentIntents() {
    console.log('called paymentIntents')
    return this
  }
  get setupIntents() {
    console.log('called setupIntents')
    return this
  }
  update(string) {
    console.log(`called update with '${string}'`)
  }
}
let stripe = new MockStripe()

function makeAStripeFN(intent) {
  return new Function(`return stripe.${intent}Intents`);
}

// 'payment' and 'setup' are values taken by req.userIntent

makeAStripeFN('payment')().update("teste")
console.log('\n')
makeAStripeFN('setup')().update("teste")
```